# Angular4: HttpClient delete request with body

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

I am upgrading my existing Angular2 application to Angular4. I have a delete request which sends body as part of the request like

```
this.http.delete('/api/deleteAddress', new RequestOptions({
   headers: headers,
   withCredentials: true,
   body: address
}));
```

New `delete` function in `HttpClient` does not have `RequestOptions`. See function declaration [here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#delete)

Question is how can I make it work with new `HttpClient`? Should I set it in `HttpParams`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(i haven't tested this)

Have you tried adding `params?:HttpParams` to your delete request options?
You have it on the link you've provided.

if that doesn't work then you can just go on with general, `request(...` method.

Comment: For any noobie like me we can, below is what is meant by request(....) in answer:
return this.httpClient.request('methoodname', url, {body : anyObject})

Answer (score 0):

```
this.http.delete('/api/deleteAddress', new RequestOptions({
   method: RequestMethod.Delete,  ====== add this.
   headers: headers,
   withCredentials: true,
   body: address
}));
```

Comment: This doesn't work with HttpClient. Parameter mismatch